# How to get the pipe commands also return output in Java exec?

Tags: java, linux, fedora

When i apply command  command i do not get any output. How can i get output while using command or not both case?

```
public class test 
{

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println(
        systemtest("ifconfig | awk 'BEGIN { FS = \"\n\"; RS = \"\" } { print $1 $2 }' | sed -e 's/ .*inet addr:/,/' -e 's/ .*//'"));   

  }

  public static String systemtest(String cmds)
  {
    String value = "";
    try 
    { 
      String cmd[] = {
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        cmds
      };       
      Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); 
      // Try 0: here? wrong
      //p.waitFor(); 
      BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
      String line=reader.readLine(); 
      // Try 1: here?
      //p.waitFor(); 
      while(line!=null) 
      { 
        value += line + "\n";
        line=reader.readLine(); 
      } 
      // Try 2: here?
      p.waitFor(); 
    } catch(IOException e1) {

    } catch(InterruptedException e2) {

    } 

    return value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the output from the command *before* you call `p.waitFor()`.

Facts:

- Output from an external command is delivered via an OS-level "pipe".
- Pipes have a limited amount of buffering.
- If some producer process tries to write to a pipe that is "full", the process is forced to wait until the consumer process has read some data from the pipe.

It is not hard to see (from the above facts) that the way that you're application is written will result in a deadlock if the external application produces more output than can fit into the pipe's buffer (in O/S space).

(Even if this is not the real cause of your problem this time, it could be other times.  Watch out for deadlocks when reading from / writing to external processes.)

Comment: p.waitFor();  i changed this in last line after while loop or before while loop. But results are same. I do not get the output yet but once i call systemtest("ifconfig"); it always outputs.

Comment: Edited the command i am trying: ifconfig | awk 'BEGIN { FS = \"\n\"; RS = \"\" } { print $1 $2 }' | sed -e 's/ .*inet addr:/,/' -e 's/ .*//'

Comment: Try something simpler, like `systemtest("ifconfig | cat")`.  I have a feeling that the problem is with the backslashes.  As written, you have an ASCII newline in a place that looks illegal in a shell command.  I'm on a Windows box right now so I can't easily check this ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how to handle stdout, stderr and stream piping.
Alternatively, you might be interested to take a look on [Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) and [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/usage.html) 
I hope it will help you.
Good luck!

Comment: Commons CLI won't help, because that's a library which _parses_ the command line. There is no support for generating a command line nor for process handling.

Comment: @A.H. I failed to recognize a correlation between the question asked and your comment. Please explain.

Comment: The question is about: "How can I *execute* a program". Commons CLI is about "When I *implement* a program, how can I parse the commandline."

Comment: @A.H. my apology! I meant Commons Exec... (Could be used in combination with Commons CLI)